# Dividing Ground-penetrating radar profile through image processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing

[image]

Please look at the attached image. It is a GPR profile and using image processing techniques, I am trying to divide this image into 3 zones by labeling with colors the whole image on the top:

1. when parabolas in the image are very clear and distinct with high pixel values - green zone/ line at the top
2. when parabolas in the image are blurred but visible - yellow zone
3. when parabolas are distorted or when not parabolas are present - red zone

What techniques should I use? What's the best approach to solve it?

I have tried various techniques but not with success in every case, because, as you can in the following image, sometimes the parabolas are too close to one another and identifying them is becoming an issue.

[image]

A sample of how I want to zone it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zm9epgf0gt7591/sample.png?dl=0
One of the tried code: simplest one.

```
clear all 
clc
%read png image
H=imread ('origpng.png');
%convert to gray scale
I = rgb2gray(H);

I(I>150)=0;I(I<100)=0;
figure,imshow(I)
J=I;
J=255-J;
figure, imshow (J)
J(J<255)=0;

figure,imshow (J)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: "Distinct" and "blurred" are not very descriptive words. How do you quantify how much a parabola has been blurred? You don't even tell us where you consider the zones to be in your sample image. For all I know, that top image could be all green.

Comment: Put this in your post.  Don't put it in a comment.  It looks ugly.

Comment: @beaker its a subjective approach.. n i am trying to automate it.. code should relatively notice the difference between parabolas with high pixel values and low, and threshold is to be automatically calculated based on the image

Comment: @rayryeng sorry i am new to this platform n didn't know how to do it..will do it now

Comment: @Kashif "its a subjective approach.."... and you still haven't even given us your subjective opinion. My subjective opinion is still to color the whole thing green.

Comment: @beaker ok..someone had already developed a manual method to color code it.. please look at the image link below: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9zm9epgf0gt7591/sample.png?dl=0 also, i need to know how to identify these parabolic regions first based on their size, pattern and/or pixel recognition.. later i work with experts on how to clearly distinguish green with yellow zones....... thank you!

Comment: LOL... I thought you were trying to divide the image into layers, like strata. Hahaha... too many unclear requirements. I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: I would forget all about parabolas, Instead divide image to vertical slices  and try just classify the dynamic range of signal there.... compute `min,max` intensity and then just compare `max-min` to some treshold/boundaries to classify the zone. If not enough maybe do some histogram comparisons instead. Without more info is hard to help more ...

Comment: I can't see a green zone on your image...

Comment: If you have access to ImageMagick (installed on most Linux distros), you can just run a Canny Edge Detector and sum down the columns for a good idea of where your sharp peaks are... `convert http://i.stack.imgur.com/XH8nq.jpg  -canny 0x1+15%+50% edges.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell its just a sample . i wanna use MATLAB software because thats just the first part, identifying object and color coding ..there's other stuff i have to do further.. thank you for your response :) do you think MATLAB is better or what you suggested?

Comment: I'm sure you can do it very well with Matlab, or OpenCV, or ImageMagick - in the end it is going to be down to the algorithms you use. Use the tools you are most comfortable with. Like @Spektre, I think parabola detection is overkill - a simple Canny Edge detector and maybe a directional filter at 30-50 degrees will find you the peaks easily enough.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks a ton for the code n thanks a lottttttt for your advice.. i am a civil enginnering student so i am not so great at coding ..so it will take some time for me to understand.. n i'll ask you questions, if any..please don't mind! n again.. thank you so very much :)

Comment: @MarkSetchell i have 2 questions: a) what's the logic for squashing n streching, i didn't get clearly so that I can code it! an b) you color coded yellow (corresponding black) and used a red mask (white color) ..what if i needed 3 colors..how should i go about it..logic i mean? :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clearly posed, but I spent some time on it and felt like sharing my thoughts. I am not preteding for an instant that this is anywhere near a complete, or rigorous answer - just some musings that might give you some ideas. Also, I use ImageMagick, but if you have and know Matlab, you should use that - I am not suggesting you switch tools.

First, I did a Canny Edge detection like this:

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITAE.png -canny 0x1+15%+50% canny.jpg
```

that gives me this:

[image]

I then *"squash"* that down till it is just 1 pixel high, which effectively totals up and averages all the columns - I make it 10 pixels high here so you can see it. Where it is white, there are lots of parabolas, elsewhere there are fewer.

[image]

Then I stretch that back up to the full height of the original image and blur it a bit - note that everything up to the following image is just one line of "code":

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITAE.png -canny 0x1+15%+50% -resize x1! -normalize -resize 827x310! -blur 0x11 -colorspace gray mask.png
```

I then use the above as an opacity mask for a red image the same size as your original like this:

```
convert -size 827x310! xc:red mask.png -compose copy-opacity -composite colouredmask.png
```

[image]

Then I took your original image and coloured it with yellow like this by first creating a yellow image and then blending it onto your image and then I blended the red image from above on top of that:

```
convert -size 827x310! xc:yellow yellow.png
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITAE.png yellow.png -compose colorize -composite colouredmask.png -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

[image]

giving

[image]

Obviously you can set different parameters and use different thresholds and things, but it kind of heads towards the sort of thing you are aiming it.

So the entire process is:

```
# Make mask of peaky areas - line 1
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITAE.png -canny 0x1+15%+50% -resize x1! -normalize -resize 827x310! -blur 0x11 -colorspace gray mask.png

# Colour mask with red - line 2
convert -size 827x310! xc:red mask.png -compose copy-opacity -composite colouredmask.png

# Tint original image with yellow and then overlay semi-transparent red area
convert -size 827x310! xc:yellow yellow.png
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITAE.png yellow.png -compose colorize -composite colouredmask.png -compose overlay -composite result.png
```

**Notes**

Squashing pixels... sorry for confusing you with my terminology! Basically, when I squash the pixels down to a single row, you need to imagine dropping a brick on the top of the image and flattening it down to just one pixel tall. So, essentially, you draw an imaginary line underneath the image and then you work across the image totalling up the number of WHITE (i.e. edge) pixels in each vertical column. Columns that have more white pixels will add up to larger numbers. Columns that have no white pixels will add up to zero. Once you have got the totals for each column, you find the highest total - let's say it is 32 and then you multiply all totals by 255/32 so that everything is normalized to 255, or white. Now the squashed strip represents the `edge energy` in each column. And I then use that as the opacity for the red when I overlay - so columns with more white edges in the Canny image will show up with more red in the result.

Let's demo what happens if I squash down to 10 pixels wide and 1 pixel high before scaling back up to the original size - basically it means that my resulting mask will have only 10 possible values (or columns) columns and that each column will be a single constant brightness. I'll put the Canny image underneath so you can see that the brightness of the squashed strip represents the `edge energy`:

```
convert https://i.stack.imgur.com/XITAE.png -canny 0x1+15%+50% -resize 10x1! -normalize -scale 827x310! mask.png
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to introduce another colour, you need to work out what your algorithm is for controlling where that colour should appear. You then do exactly the same thing again - you make a mask that is light where you want that colour in your output image and dark where you don't want that colour. Then you use that mask as the opacity for your new colour (as I did at the line labelled `line 2` above) and then you overlay it like I did in the last line of my code above.

Comment: Great job Mark.  I didn't touch this question because I really didn't understand what the requirements are.

Comment: @rayryeng I don't think I understand the requirements fully either - but it was an interesting question and, while understandable in the circumstances, none of the comments actually offered anything very concrete so I thought I'd make an effort to share some ideas at least and see if that got the ball rolling. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thank you very much for the explanation and the answer.. I can tell you how greatly you have helped me..and I am sorry I couldn't explain the requirements very clearly because the requirements itself are subjective and I have to further look into the whole approach for a viable solution ..but you sure have "got the ball rolling" :) :) really appreciated!!