# How to remove image noise (horizontal lines) while filling the hyperbolas? Idea requested :)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, noise-reduction, imagefilter

I have an image as showin in '1'.
I applied Hessian filter to get the result '2'.
I applied Standard filter (stdfilt) in MATLAB to get the result as in '3'.

I wish to combine these two results into a single image such that:

- the horizontal lines (noise in my case) are removed.
- the hyperbolic areas are filled.

How could I obtain such a result?

Original (1):

[image: Original Image]

Hessian (2):

[image: Hessian]

stdfilt (3):

[image: stdfilt]

Last two without markups:

[image: Hessian_copy]

[image: stdfilt_copy]

Comment: Can't guess what you expect the result to be.

Comment: @YvesDaoust . Thanks for your reply! I would like the result to be filled hyperbolas (mostly) with lesser noise - especially no horizontal white bands .

Comment: You already said that. Repeating is of no use.

Comment: The lower horizontal line you point to is formed by the cusps of hyperbolas. Why remove those? Anyway, it seems what you want to do is detect those hyperbolas, rather than attempt to filter out stuff?

Comment: curious picture. what is being imaged and how is it imaged? -- I concur. focus on detecting what you want, rather than removing things you don't want, because removal introduces new artefacts that make your life harder. if you told us what you're really after, we could help more effectively... [your previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33241209/dividing-ground-penetrating-radar-profile-through-image-processing) indicate that this is "ground-penetrating radar"

Comment: you might want to train a (fully convolutional) neural network to detect these things, i.e. infer a heatmap where each local maximum is the cusp of a parabola -- your input image appears a little "overexposed", displayed with too much contrast. the white portions are clearly saturated. you're losing information there. -- would recommend that you tag `computer-vision` and `object-detection`

Comment: Thanks Cris and @ChristophRackwitz .. yes, indeed my main goal is  to detect hyperbolas ( I have already a developed a code for it) in these ground penetrating radar images. Here, i wish to remove reduce noise as a pre-processing step for better detection rate

Answer (score 0):

You can start by binarizing your image. I recommend opencv `otsu` threshold. it will be hard to solve this problem if gradients are present. After the image is binarized, you will need to fix bridging between the parabolas and the horizontal lines. I recommend morphological erosion, but I am still experimenting with this in my own projects. After that, you can use watershed or DBSCAN to flood-fill each region with a given marker or color. You can then filter out the horizontal lines by pixel count, since they will be much larger than a single parabola. If erosion+DBSCAN doesn't work reliably, you can look into opencv's `connectedComponents` function.

See:

```
https://iq.opengenus.org/connected-component-labeling/
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/db4/tutorial_py_watershed.html
```